Allow APIs in azure multi-tenant ADB2C to be consume by another tenant client app
I am working on .net web api and reacts app projects and registered in azure different tenant; Azure Active Directory B2C (ADB2C)
Tenant A: Web API project
Tenant B: React Client App1 (this need to consume APIs from Tenant A)
Tenant C: React Client App2 (this need to consume APIs from Tenant A)
I am unable to see APIs in Tenant B / C under API Permission and stuck over here..
In Tenant A: I have scope
https://MyMachine.onmicrosoft.com/api/xxx/Core.API.All

and then under Tenant A; API Permission --> I added 'Application Permission' for APIs
In Manifest I can see
"signInAudience": "AzureADMultipleOrgs",


I have same owner in all tenants
what else i need to do to have API from Tenant A to be accessible on tenant B and C
i have created consent url which ask me to authorise but i still not able to see Core.API.All in tenant B/C under API Permission
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{TenantA TenantID}/adminconsent?client_id={TenantB : ClientID}&redirect_uri=http://localhost:3000/auth-callback




Check this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/25329/in-azure-ad-how-to-access-an-api-registered-as-mul

Refer to the official Azure AD B2C documentation for detailed guidance on multi-tenant API access scenarios: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/

In B2C TenantA, I created a Multitenant application and exposed an API, added scope:

Granted API permissions:

To get this TenantA as Enterprise application in TenantB, run the below and sign in with TenantB user:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=TenantAWebProjecttAppID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&response_mode=fragment&scope=https://b2caadtenant.onmicrosoft.com/xxx/Core.API.All&state=12345


An Enterprise application will be created in TenantB. To grant the API permissions to the Enterprise application in TenantB, run the below and sign in TenantB user:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/adminconsent?client_id=TenantAWebProjecttAppID


In TenantB, the Enterprise application now has permissions granted:

Now create the application in TenantB and add the API permission of TenantAWebProjectt like below:

Now TenantB client app will be able to consume APIs from TenantA and do the same with TenantC.

thanks for the detail answer .. i am trying this as i am getting other error which i trying to sort out

getting error after consent url enter Sign in
Sorry, but we’re having trouble with signing you in.
xxDSTS500xxx: The resource principal named https://MyMachine.onmicrosoft.com/api was not found in the tenant named Mymachine.onmicrosoft.com. This can happen if the application has not been installed by the administrator of the tenant or consented to by any user in the tenant. You might have sent your authentication request to the wrong tenant.

Is the Enterprise application created in TenantB?

i have update question with image of Api permission of tenant which holds the web api registered application

For which URL are you getting this error?

Tenant A have web api project
Tenant B has client app registered
not sure what you mean by Is the Enterprise application created in TenantB?
yes there is app registered

@K.Z you have to create Enterprise application of tenantA application in TenantB for that you need to construct the Authorize url and sign in with TenantB user and the construct admin consent url. Check my answer that is the 3rd image

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

i have managed to sorted based on your guideline
